# The process cannot access the file 'd:\1.doc' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#-4.0, file-io

my code :

```
 object c = "d:\\1.doc";

        if(File.Exists(c.ToString()))
        {
            File.Delete(c.ToString());
        }
```

error :

> The process cannot access the file 'd:\1.doc' because it is being used
>   by another process.

How close ? with code

Comment: What don't you understand in that error message?

Comment: Go download `unlocker` tool and see what exactly has it locked by the OS (http://www.filehippo.com/download_unlocker)

Comment: @ja72 - Nice! Thanks for this! This was one of those things I didn't realize that I wanted until just this moment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all use `string` instead of `object`, so:

```
string c = "d:\\1.doc";
```

now as the message indicated the file being used by another process. either by windows process, or you are opening the file stream and forget to close it. check in your code where you are interacting with the file.

**Edit:** Since you are using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` make sure you close the file(s) open first like:

```
Word.ApplicationClass word = new Word.ApplicationClass();

//after using it:

if (word.Documents.Count > 0)
{
    word.Documents.Close(...);
}

((Word._Application)word.Application).Quit(..);

word.Quit(..);
```

Comment: no. I am using the object for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.   oWordDoc.SaveAs(ref c, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
      ref oMissing
      , ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing, ref oMissing,
      ref oMissing, ref oMissing
      , ref oMissing, ref oMissing); c as object. not string.

Comment: I see, ok, so don't forget to close the opened files before you try to delete them. I updated the answer to show you how.

Comment: @mrJack did my answer solves your issue? if that is the case then don't forget to mark it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) so other members/visitors will know it helps you.

Comment: @ Jalal Aldeen Saa'd : if the file has been closed in bad way,for example an error caused the program closed but the file is still open (the process is runing in TaskManger),how to close that when the program runs again?

Comment: @raha: Well, in that case you should save the file(s) name(s) that you open them, and remove that name(s) when you close that file gracefully, then whenever your application starts, search for those files names "your last open files", if any of then found kill its process...

Comment: @ Jalal Aldeen Saa'd: when the process is runing ,you can't delete that.you should kill the process and it's imposible,because the name of process is WINWORD.EXE,and if you close that,all word document will be closed.

Comment: @raha: 1- each time you open a work document it will create a new process with name `WINWORD.EXE` so killing one will not affect the others, however to know the file name you can call API for instance that checks windows names...., or Better is to use Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application") an example can be found [HERE](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/185554/Getting-currently-open-MS-word-insatnce-count-and), hope it helped

Answer (score 1):

I had the same type of issue when I wanted to Delete File after Open/Read it using  `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word` and I needed to close my document and the application like that :

```
 private void parseFile(string filePath)
        {
            // Open a doc file.
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application application = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application();
            Document document = application.Documents.Open(filePath);

            // Loop through all words in the document.
            int count = document.Words.Count;
            for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
            {
                // Write the word.
                string text = document.Words[i].Text;
                Console.WriteLine("Word {0} = {1}", i, text);
            }

            // Close document correctly
            ((_Document)document).Close();
            ((_Application)application).Quit();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have that file actively open in this or another program, and Windows prevents you from deleting it in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the file still running (opened) by another application
1- `Microsoft Word`
2- `WordPad`